# data.table modify by reference with unexpected result

Tags: r, data.table

When I create a column by reference using the `:=` operator of the R package `data.table`, I obtain a somewhat unexpected result:

```
dt <- data.table(A = c(NA, "050", "050", "050"), 
             B = c(NA, "00", "00", "02"),
             C = c(NA, "00", "01", "02"))
> dt
     A  B  C  
1:  NA NA NA 
2: 050 00 00 
3: 050 00 01 
4: 050 02 02
```

Adding a column gives:

```
dt[B == "00" & C == "00", lev := 1]
> dt[lev == 1, .N]
[1] 1
```

When modifying the column, I obtain however

```
dt[B == "00" & C != "00", lev := 2]
> dt[lev == 1, .N]
[1] 0
```

although the second value of column `lev` is still equal to `1`:

```
> dt
     A  B  C lev
1:  NA NA NA  NA
2: 050 00 00   1
3: 050 00 01   2
4: 050 02 02  NA
```

Do I miss something here?

```
> packageVersion("data.table")
[1] ‘1.9.4’
```

Comment: In the devel version, I get `1`

Comment: I see the same behavior as the OP, but also see `dt[lev==1L,.N]` giving 1. I guess the column got converted to integer or something. (Also 1.9.4 here.)

Comment: hmm, I take it back, it's not a precision issue as `dt[, lev == 1]` works as expected, not sure why `dt[lev == 1]` doesn't, could be the auto-indexing thing again

Comment: yeah, it's definitely auto-indexing (which I think has been fixed), so just turn it off - `options(datatable.auto.index=FALSE)`, or upgrade to devel

Comment: @eddi Yes, switching off auto-indexing gives the expected result.